# If for any $\epsilon>0$, $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty P [|X| > n \epsilon ]< \infty $, then $E| X| < \infty $?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Suppose that given any $\epsilon>0$, $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty P [|X| > n
>  \epsilon ]< \infty. $$ Does this imply that $$ E| X| < \infty \quad ?$$

I made the obvious attempt
\begin{align*}
E| X| &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int 1_{\{|X| \in (\epsilon(n-1), \epsilon n)\}}|X | dP\\
&\le \sum_{n=0} ^\infty \epsilon n P\{|X| \in (\epsilon(n-1), \epsilon n)\} \\
&\le \epsilon \sum_{n=1}^\infty n P\{ |X | \ge \epsilon n \}.
\end{align*}
But this does not seem to leed to the desired conclusion.

Most grateful for any help provided!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given condition is too strong to imply the given result. This holds even if
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P [|X| > n
 \epsilon_0 ]< \infty$$
for a particular $\epsilon_0>0$ (need not hold for all positive $\epsilon$, as given).

To show this, note that
\begin{align}
E|X|&=\int_0^\infty P(|X|>x)dx\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{(n-1)\epsilon_0}^{n\epsilon_0} P(|X|>x)dx\\
&\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty \epsilon_0P(|X|>(n-1)\epsilon_0)\\
&\le\epsilon_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \epsilon_0P(|X|>n\epsilon_0)
\end{align}
which is finite.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Replace the last line by $\leq\epsilon\sum nP(\epsilon (n-1) \leq |X| <\epsilon n)$ and use summation by parts.

[ $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n(a_{n-1}-a_n) =\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ if we define $a_0$ as $0$. Take $a_n= P(|X| >\epsilon n)$].

Note that single $\epsilon$ will do.